# Modal popup extender in datalist

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender, datalist

I have the below code inside the datalist control

```
  <a  id="lnkCart" runat="server" onclick="lnkCart_Click" title='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BookId")%>'>
         <img src="images/cart.gif" id='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BookId")%>'
               alt="" title="" border="0" class="left_bt" />

       </a>
```

Now I want that on click of the above link I would show the modal pop up, but this modal popup should load the information from the database based on the book Id which I can get from the title of the 'a' link. So, that I need to get the BookId at the server side and have to load the content in the panel which is need to be updated. Can it be easy by using the modal pop up extender?

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will have to put panel and fill this panel from "ItemDataBound" property of datalist by fetching bookid. See below code

```
 protected void dlalbumlist_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
                     e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
// Code to fill panel from bookid using findcontrol get hyperlink 
            }

        }

    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdl" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnl" TargetControlID="lnkCart" CancelControlID="btn" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>    
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" style="display:none;" Width="300px" Height="300px"   BackColor="red">
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
```

Comment: Thanks! is there any way I can load the panel content when I click on the link? Because if I load everything on ItemDataBound Event then it will take a very long time to load.

Comment: Fill the panel Using ajaxmethod or pagemethod and call from javascript function. function will be called from anchor tag.